# Mysql, one column value changes bases on other column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

this is the table:

table_test

```
ID------INT
DETAIL--TEXT
VALUE---INT
STATUS--INT DEFAULT 1
```

as here the default value will be 1 for column `STATUS` and default value will be 1 for column `VALUE`.

Here in any case of **insert** or **update**,

```
if column VALUE < 1 , STATUS = 2 else STATUS = 1
```

How can I keep the upper type scenario in MySQL table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a couple of triggers:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER table_test_update_tr BEFORE UPDATE ON table_test
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.value < 0 THEN
            SET NEW.status = 2;
        ELSE
            SET NEW.status = 1;
        END IF;
    END;//
delimiter ;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER table_test_insert_tr BEFORE INSERT ON table_test
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.value < 0 THEN
            SET NEW.status = 2;
        ELSE
            SET NEW.status = 1;
        END IF;
    END;//
delimiter ;
```

EDIT:
Having said that, if `status` should always be computed according to `value`, perhaps it shouldn't be a column in the table - instead, you can create a view to display it.

```
CREATE TABLE table_test (
    id INT,
    detail TEXT,
    value INT DEFAULT 1
);

CREATE VIEW view_test AS
SELECT id, 
       detail, 
       value, 
       CASE value WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS status
FROM   test_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)  for this :

```
UPDATE  table_test
SET     STATUS =
        CASE
        WHEN VALUE < 1 THEN 2
        ELSE 1
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create a TRIGGER on UPDATE and on INSERT

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `Ins_test_table` AFTER INSERT
    ON `test_table`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF (VALUE < 1) THEN
    SET STATUS = 2;
    ELSE SET STATUS = 1;
    END IF;
    END$$ 

  CREATE
    TRIGGER `Update_test_table` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `test_table`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF (VALUE < 1) THEN
    SET STATUS = 2;
    ELSE SET STATUS = 1;
    END IF;
    END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

ALSO if you can run other MYSQL query - you can RUN this query.

```
UPDATE test_table
SET STATUS = IF (VALUE < 1, 2, 1)
```

But its a higest load on all table.